# Does master record (having rollup summary field) always get updated when a child record is updated?

Tags: apex, master-detail, roll-up-summary

Does master record (having rollup summary field) always get updated when a child record is updated regardless of the change in value of rollup summary field? In short, will the last modified date updated every time a child record is created or updated regardless of any change in the roll up summary field value?

Comment: Yes, master record with rollup summery value always updated regardless of any change in rollup summery value

Comment: Hi @SantanuBoral, Thanks for quick reply. Do you have any reference to the Salesforce documentation?

Comment: I read earlier during my exam preparation, i will send you later